# Authenticate Express app with Passport.JS and ADFS

Tags: node.js, passport.js, adfs, ws-federation

I'm trying to authenticate my Express app with ADFS using passport.js. I'm using the passport-wsfed-saml2 passport.js strategy and *think* I have everything as I should, but I have a problem logging in.

Launching my app (http://localhost:8011) redirects me to the ADFS login page. Great. I enter my login credentials for a user I added to the AD and receive an error....

```
Activity ID: 4fcc86b2-165d-4199-1d00-0080000000f3
Error details: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: g
Node name: f5c76cf3-a6a3-41c6-8584-37594f31107e
Error time: Tue, 30 Jun 2020 01:36:20 GMT
Cookie: enabled
User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
```

The event log on the ADFS server isn't much help...

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
wsfed 

Relying Party: 
 

Exception details: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.GetContextFromWCtx(WSFederationContext federationPassiveContext, Boolean deleteCookie)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.GetOriginalRequestFromResponse(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

So, what am I doing wrong? And how can I investigate this further to figure out what is happening?

The configuration I'm working with is one server, running Windows Server 2019 configured as a DC and running ADFS. This is a test configuration to prove I can authenticate my app with ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

Initially check whether you were able to access the IDP initiated page or not.
https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.htm.

"Encountered error due to passive request" will occur in various scenarios .

Enable admin and trace logs of the ADFS . The Trace log is where detailed messages are logged, and will be the most useful log when troubleshooting. It is disabled by default an you can enable both the logs, check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-logging) to enable.

You can also use [fiddler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-fiddler-ws-fed) to understand the flow and troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I was using Azure Gov. When I switched to Azure Commerical everything worked as expected.